# Cannot see the STORAGE_GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT in my google cloud account when setting up storage integration

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am following the steps here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-gcs.html and having trouble on step 6

I ran:

```
create storage integration my_integration
                                                   type = external_stage
                                                   storage_provider = gcs
                                                   enabled = TRUE
                                                   STORAGE_ALLOWED_LOCATIONS = ('gcs://<my-bucket>')
                                                   ;
```

which completed successfully. Then `DESC STORAGE INTEGRATION MY_INTEGRATION;` successfully describes the storage integration and lists a STORAGE_GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT

However I cannot find this service account in the google cloud platform console that owns that bucket.

My snowflake account is on AWS though according to that tutorial page, I am allowed to use AWS or CGP for this integration.

Is there somewhere I should indicate in the create integration command which google cloud project I am referring to so that it knows where to create the service account?

And advice on performing this step?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was because my bucket was not publicly accessible. Once I turned it to publicly accessible I was able to find that service account when adding roles.

It appears that the service account is not a service account "On" the google cloud platform account that hosts the bucket but rather one setup by snowflake on their own managed services.

So its like granting an external storage account permissions rather than an internal one.